# Why do some users have a grey avatar?

Tags: support, user-accounts

Seems no one has asked this before:

[image: Screenshot of a post signature]

The profile looks weird; it has no link in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The account doesn't exist. It can happen if the question was migrated from another site and the user has no account here, or if the account has been deleted since the question was asked